# Regular Expression Select text between spaces

Tags: .net, regex

I need to extract the text between spaces within a string. In the sample below I'm looking to extract the text '401900 PRE' into a group named Recipe. The group Recipe must not return any white space after the letters PRE. Here's what I have at the moment. '401900 PRE    Current User' gets printed to screen. I can't figure out how to stop after PRE.

The 401900 PRE text changes regularly but the other text elements are constant.

```
        string recipe = "<OPERATE MODE> - 401900 PRE    Current User";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@".*<OPERATE MODE> - (?'Recipe'.*\ *)");
        MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(recipe);

        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Recipe"]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `PRE` always there?

Comment: No, 401900 PRE could change to 502700 PRO for example.

Comment: @Lance will it always be one number and one word?

Comment: No, could be anything but will always have <OPERATE MODE> - before it and Current User after it (with spaces preceding Current User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the constant stuff you don't want to match in the pattern:

```
@".*<OPERATE MODE> - (?'Recipe'.*?)\s+Current User"
```

Note that you need to make the repetition inside the group [ungreedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), otherwise it will consume some of the spaces.

Comment: Thanks, can;t believe i didn't think of that. Both answers work great. I'm going to give the answer to p.s.w.g as he get in first.

Comment: @Lance not according to my clock ;). But go ahead please, his answer is more complete.

Comment: @Lance Thanks, but actually *m.buettner* was first. Both solutions work, depending on what characters you know will follow your pattern. Mine assumes 2 whitespace characters, *m.buettner*'s assumes at least one whitespace character and the string `Current User`. You should select the answer which best suits your needs or most completely answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern

```
<OPERATE MODE> - (?'Recipe'.*?)\s{2}
```

Should work. This will match a literal `<OPERATE MODE> -` followed by any text captured  in the group, `Recipe`, stopping at the first two white space characters.

For example:

```
string recipe = "<OPERATE MODE> - 401900 PRE    Current User";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"<OPERATE MODE> - (?'Recipe'.*?)\s{2}");
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(recipe);

foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Recipe"]);  // 401900 PRE
}
```